# How to use customized key to start visual block selection in VIM

Tags: vim

I know VIM can start visual block selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, or sometimes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> becomes pasting, we can still go with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>. But I think this key combination is not so easy to press, can I assign a customized key for this? For example, I would like to use <kbd>q</kbd> in normal mode to start visual selection (I don't use macro recording that much):

`map q ???` <-- what should I write here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you're looking for

```
:nnoremap q <c-v>
```

But note that you won't be able to record macros unless you remap that too.

Comment: Thanks! That works! And I find by similar way I can still have macro recording working with a longer key seq:

:nnoremap qq q